# Set random seed or prevent arbor.js from producing a different graph every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, arbor.js

I am using arbor.js to create a virtual network graph. However, every time the page is refreshed, a completely different graph is drawn. This can be confusing to the user who will not be able to easily find what they were looking at. Is there any way to set the random seed or somehow keep the graph looking the same?